# What does crash (50+08:39) part mean?

Tags: vps

When I issue

```
last | grep root
```

in terminal to check login histories to my server, from among various lines, I also get the following.

```
root     pts/0        IP address    Mon Jun 16 15:03 - crash (50+08:39)
```

I just want to know what the "crash (50+08:39)" part mean?

PS: Since I have newly installed the OS, I suspect the IP address belongs to the company I bought the VPS from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means root had been logged in for 50 days, 8 hours and 39 minutes, on pts/0, from the IP address specified, when the system crashed.  From the timings, I'm guessing the system crashed around 23:42 local time on Aug 5.

**Edit**: It depends on what your VPS does under the hood when you click "*reinstall the OS*", and without asking your provider, there's no way of knowing that. If you had done a complete, clean reinstall of the OS, re-mkfs'ing the file systems and reinstalling all content, I don't think any login information could possibly have persisted across that. But since login information did persist, we can only infer that your VPS provider does something less than a complete wipe-and-reinstall when you ask for a rebuild.

Since you say you did a "*rebuild*" yesterday, from the other information provided I'm guessing that your VPS provider left a stray root login hanging around - possibly on some kind of virtual console - for some time, and that when you clicked on "*rebuild the OS*" that login was terminated as part of the rebuild.

But without talking to your VPS provider for specifics, there's no way to be sure.

Comment: Thanks. Strange. I rebulit the system only yesterday. What does that mean?

Comment: I have no idea.  What do you mean by "*rebuilt*" - not the same thing I do, I'm guessing.

Comment: I mean reinstalled the OS. That's what it is called in my VPS panel.